# What is an efficient way to remove unknown values of attributes in a data set or delete a row in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am reading the data set of [Arrhythmia](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/arrhythmia/arrhythmia.data), and some attributes are missing (when this happens, they put '**?**'). For example:

```
... 64, -2, ?, 63, 0, ...
```

How should I treat this example? Is it better to get rid of the unknown values when I am doing some statistical analysis?

How do I remove data containing '**?**' in MATLAB?

Comment: This depends entirely on what type of analysis you're trying to do.  This question is probably better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I don't think this should be moved, since it also asks how the `?` can be removed in Matlab. A related question that explains explicitly what statistics should be done would fit well on CrossValidated, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the string, use [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) and [STR2DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2double.html), which will replace missing values by `NaN` (for many statistical analysis, you don't want to just delete the value, but rather you want to know something's missing). Most functions of the stats toolbox, as well as e.g. `plot` can handle `NaN`.

For example

```
tmp = textscan('-2,**?**,63,0','%s','delimiter',',')
str2double(tmp{1})
ans =
    -2
   NaN
    63
     0
```

Comment: I f I import to matlab a data set, how would the code look like:
`A = load('A.txt');
tmp = textscan(A...) 
str2double(tmp...) `